# Unit Test code called supresses Debug.WriteLine and Trace.WriteLine

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-debugging

I have some code that I need to see when I am running a test, and
TestContext would have to be part of my Test class I need the
debug.writelines of the class being tested displayed. I considered
just passing a TestContext to my MessageStatus static method and may
have to but that will be a PITA because the UnitTest class would have
to pass the TestContext to the object it is testing. Too tightly
coupled for my taste.

In basic terms

```
 [TestMethod]
       public void TestA()
       {
           //....
           Assert.IsTrue(Blah.Blah()));
       }



public void Blah()
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Hello");
}
```

never shows up when I run the unit tests!

I could change it to:

```
TestContext t;
 [TestMethod]
       public void TestA()
       {
           //....
           Assert.IsTrue(Blah.Blah(t)));
       }



public void Blah(TestContext p1)
{
    p1.WriteLine("Hello");
}
```

but that is insane it means changing all my signatures and tight coupling.  I read the thread at [How to write output from a unit test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4786884/debug-writeline-doesnt-work-from-within-unit-tests) it does not help :(

Answer (score 2):

If you need to see lines produced by Debug.WriteLine or deal with assertions produced by Debug.Assert you can create your own System.Diagnostic.TraceListener to redirect output to TestContext - see my answer [What do I have to do so that assertions won't block automated tests anymore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5504183/what-do-i-have-to-do-so-that-assertions-wont-block-automated-tests-anymore).

```
public class MyListenerThatDoesNotShowDialogOnFail: 
       System.Diagnostics.TraceListener
{
    // This is to avoid message box on Debug.Assert(false);
    public override void Fail(string message, string detailMessage)
    {// do something UnitTest friendly here like Assert.Fail(false)
    }

    // This (+Write) is to redirect Debug.WriteLine("Some trace text");
    public override void WriteLine(string message)
    {// do something UnitTest friendly here like TestContext.Write(message)
    }
}
```

Somewhere in the test setup listener. Note that sample below is simplified, you probably want to save current listeners and restore at the end of test.

```
Debug.Listeners.Clear();
Debug.Listeners.Add(new MyListenerThatDoesNotShowDialogOnFail());
```

Comment: See example of TraceListener that simply appends trace messages to a string at [Trace listener to write to a text box (WPF application)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1389289)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Console.WriteLine` for the output to show up in the test runner. However, this is a **bad thing**. I recommend using a logging framework like nlog.